# How to make the tab names visible in the main codeblocks window?

Tags: codeblocks

I sorry to ask this lame question but I'ev searched everywhere else and could not find an answer.
The bar that show the tab name in codeblocks is gone.when I open multiple files I don't know which one I am in.This is bothering me.How can I get it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**View -> Hide editor tabs**, try it and I guess your tab name would come back.

View -> perspectives -> Code::Blocks default may also work.

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck the View->Hide editor tabs option. It worked.